# How to restrict any DML operation in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to insert some records into a table for a particular month. How do I restrict any DML operations on that table for rest of the other months in a stored procedure (without any trigger or constraints). Please help me on this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including: an example of the procedure you are using; an example of how your end user will be calling that procedure; details of your tables.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the "particular month" as a parameter and use it in code throughout the procedure, most probably in `WHERE` clauses or `IF`s, `CASE`s etc.

Comment: that we can pass it but how we can restrict the end user when he will be inserting or updating to the table for any other months.

Comment: Create additional table, maintained by YOU, which will contain only allowed month(s). Reference that table from the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 users:

- The first (we can call it `DATA_OWNER`) will own the tables containing the data and the stored procedures/packages that perform the DML on those tables; and
- The second (we can call it `END_USER`) will be the database user that your end users connect as.

Then you can create the tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE data_owner.table_name (
  id       NUMBER
           GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
           PRIMARY KEY,
  datetime DATE
           NOT NULL,
  value    NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE data_owner.table_name_insert_bounds (
  start_datetime DATE,
  end_datetime DATE,
  CONSTRAINT table_name_insert_bounds__pk PRIMARY KEY ( start_datetime, end_datetime ),
  CONSTRAINT table_name_insert_bounds__chk CHECK ( start_datetime <= end_datetime )
);
```

And a package containing your stored procedures:

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE data_owner.table_name_management_pkg IS
  PROCEDURE add_value(
    i_datetime IN  TABLE_NAME.DATETIME%TYPE,
    i_value    IN  TABLE_NAME.VALUE%TYPE
  );
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY data_owner.table_name_management_pkg IS
  PROCEDURE add_value(
    i_datetime IN  TABLE_NAME.DATETIME%TYPE,
    i_value    IN  TABLE_NAME.VALUE%TYPE
  )
  IS
    valid_datetime NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT CASE
           WHEN EXISTS(
                  SELECT 1
                  FROM   table_name_insert_bounds
                  WHERE  i_datetime BETWEEN start_datetime AND end_datetime
                )
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
           END
    INTO   valid_datetime
    FROM   DUAL;
    
    IF valid_datetime = 0 THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(
        -20000,
        'Date-time is outside of current insertion range.'
      );
    END IF;
    
    INSERT INTO table_name ( datetime, value )
    VALUES ( i_datetime, i_value );
  END;
END;
/
```

And then grant permissions to the end user:

```sql
GRANT SELECT ON data_owner.table_name TO end_user;
GRANT EXECUTE ON data_owner.table_name_management_pkg TO end_user;
```

Then the end user can only perform DML actions via the stored procedure in the package (they have no permissions to perform DML directly on the table bypassing the procedure) but could also `SELECT` all the data and the data owner can set the date bounds which the end user is able to insert within (and the end user cannot modify these bounds).

For example:

If the data owner sets these boundaries:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name_insert_bounds ( start_datetime, end_datetime )
VALUES ( DATE '2020-01-01', DATE '2020-02-01' );
```

Then the end user can run:

```sql
BEGIN
  data_owner.table_name_management_pkg.ADD_VALUE( DATE '2020-01-10', 42 );
END;
/
```

and one row will be inserted but if they try to:

```sql
BEGIN
  data_owner.table_name_management_pkg.ADD_VALUE( DATE '2020-02-02', 13 );
END;
/
```

Then will get the exception:

> ```
> ORA-20000: Date-time is outside of current insertion range.
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=af069973396ba0a8906ba6fc42cb763a)*